# How to display the total number of article/page on a term views?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

In Drupal 7. We created a Views to list all pages assigned to this particular TermA. But some of these pages can only be view by registered user. We would like to show the total number of pages in this TermA, so un-registered user know how many articles/pages they are missing without register. So how can I display the total number of pages in this TermA in View(not the term menu link)? It will be nice to show that number next to(or under) the Views title(see screenshots).

***Current setting on views and display***
[image]
[image]

***wanna have total number of articles in this TermA like this***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by creating view attachment or block which will calculate the total number of nodes per term. Do not add access rule for this case. This can be then called in the header of the Taxonomy Term View using Global:View where you can select the newly created view and its display.

Comment: I added an attachment with header "Global:Result summery". It does show the total of pages on that term. "But" it does not show the original total pages in this term if the user does not have the permission to views these pages. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you set the Access of the Attachment Display as None, it should work this way.

Comment: yes, the Access on Attachment is set as "None". But some pages are only for registered user only.